# Java - Two dimensional system for a board

Tags: java, game-engine, multidimensional-array

I am making a board for the game sokoban with Java.

I wonder what would be the best implementation?

Arrays? ArrayLists? Lists?

The pieces would be represented as a string at this time, but might be objects at a later time. I could not find information about which system is best suited for such a field.

Edit: Conclusion:

```
List<List<Object>> list = new ArrayList<List<Object>>();
```

Comment: Will the board change its size?

Comment: No, only during the initial startup. It will be defined by two variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the size is constant then arrays would be fine . Since they might be objects at later so better to use `List` implementations.

Comment: As in: `List<Object> field = new ArrayList<Object>();` ?

Comment: Ya as you have mentioned *might be objects at a later time* in your question. I think they are custom objects.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the best aproach would be an 2D-Array. But keep in mind that you can't change the field size later.

```
string[][] field = new string[F_WIDTH][F_HEIGHT];
```

The pros are that an 2D-Arary is easy to access and faster than an ArrayList, but as i mentioned befre after creation it has a fixed size

If you want to do that you should use a kind of dynamic List, for example an ArrayList.

And for your information: [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) is just an interface, so its not really an independent kind of Lists it justs abstracts properties of many other implementations